# iptables for routing a single user to openvpn on tun0, and deny eth0 access?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I am trying to route one users traffic through openvpn. Their traffic should be denied if the vpn goes down. I want to do this with a script attached to openvpn.

In my testing, this works for routing user through vpn until i use the DROP iptable... then the user loses all connectivity and the other rules are ignored..

this is all on debian stretch.

i found a nice comprehensive howto here: https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/08/28/making-all-network-traffic-for-a-linux-user-use-a-specific-network-interface/comment-page-1/

and it works well, for the most part, except that I have the same problem as before. I can route traffic for a user to the vpn, but if the vpn is not present it falls back to eth0 or whatever.

if I try to prevent this with the equivalent of "allow on `tun0`, don't allow `eth0`" I end up blocking tun0 as well as eth0"

`iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j REJECT`
conflicts with

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT
```

what am I doing wrong here?

below was my first attempt, but now I am following the format of the link above:

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner foo -j MARK --set-mark 42
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 10.20.0.0/24 -m owner --uid-owner foo
iptables -I OUTPUT -d VPNSERVERIP -p udp -j ACCEPT -m owner --uid-owner foo
iptables -I OUTPUT -j DROP -m owner --uid-owner foo
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and then some other stuff to get the routing working...

```
ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42

for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do
    echo 0 > $f
    done;
ip route add default via $(ifconfig -a tun0 | grep -o 'destination [^ ]*' | cut -d \  -f 2) table 42
```

after all this `iptables -L OUTPUT` looks like this:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match foo
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             VPNSERVERIP       owner UID match foo
           all  --  anywhere             10.20.0.0/24         owner UID match foo
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match foo MARK set 0x2a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the following configuration:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -m comment --comment "Block Broadcast INPUT (No log)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -m comment --comment "Block Multicast INPUT (No Log)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost Input" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 1194 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow the server to reply (related to lport)" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow the DNS1 to answer" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.8.4.4/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow the DNS2 to answer" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "Log Input" -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP INPUT: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i tun+ -m comment --comment "Accept TUN Input" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "Log Forward" -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP FORWARD: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s $EXTERNALIP -o $EXT_INT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s $EXTERNALIP/32 -o $EXT_INT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s $EXTERNALIP/32 -o $EXT_INT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost Output" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m comment --comment "Allow my computer to query the DNS server" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o $EXT_INT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o $EXT_INT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow my machine to connect to the DNS1" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.4.4/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow my machine to connect to the DNS2" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "Log Output" -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP OUTPUT: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow ping to Outside" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -m comment --comment "Accept TUN Output" -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help:

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/3615/howto-ubuntu-debian-block-all-traffic-on-the-eth-card-and-use-only-the-vpn-updated

They've blocked all traffic to eth0, then allowed some to pass later (DNS, ping)

> goldsztajn
>
> August 2014 in General Privacy Discussion
>
> Posts: 4
>
> (UPDATED)
>
> Hi everybody,
>
> I have tried to build a solution that will transform a Debian or Ubuntu machine to be able to access the Internet ONLY via the VPN (to avoid any mistake if you are disconnected or if OpenVPN crashes).
>
> For your information, I use OpenVPN configured with the PIA config files and I assume you have only the eth0 on your computer.
>
> 1/ When the interfaces goes up, disable the trafic
>
> /etc/network/interfaces
>
> ```
>    auto eth0
>
>    iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
>        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
> ```
>
> Then : /etc/iptables.rules
>
> ```
>    *filter
>
>    # Default Policy
>
>    :INPUT DROP [0:0]
>
>    :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
>
>    :OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
>
>    # Broadcast without logging
>
>    -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP -m comment --comment "Block Broadcast INPUT (No log)"
>
>    -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j DROP -m comment --comment "Block Multicast INPUT (No Log)"
>
>    # Allow localhost
>
>    -A INPUT  -i lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost Input" -j ACCEPT
>
>    -A OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost Output" -j ACCEPT
>
>    ## Allow to connect to upd 1194 (openvpn)
>
>    -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow my computer to query the DNS server"
>
>    -A INPUT  -p udp --sport 1194 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  -m comment --comment "Allow the server to reply (related to lport)"
>
>    # Allow DNS
>
>    -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 209.222.18.222 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow my machine to connect to the DNS1"
>
>     -A INPUT  -p udp -s 209.222.18.222 --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow the DNS1 to answer"
>
>    -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 209.222.18.218 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow my machine to connect to the DNS2"
>
>    -A INPUT  -p udp -s 209.222.18.218 --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow the DNS2 to answer"
>
>    # Logging
>
>    -A INPUT -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP INPUT: " --log-level 7 -m comment --comment "Log Input"
>
>    -A FORWARD -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP FORWARD: " --log-level 7 -m comment --comment "Log Forward"
>
>    -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP OUTPUT: " --log-level 7 -m comment --comment "Log Output"
>
>    # Ping
>
>    -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ping to Outside"
>
>    COMMIT
> ```
>
> Then if you don't start your VPN, you have ... nothing, except localhost, DNS and OpenVPN
>
> To apply the changes :
>
> ```
>    # ifdown eth0
>
>    # ifup eth0
> ```
>
> When you start your VPN, to avoid DNS Leak I launch a script
>
> I had to "hack" the /etc/default/openvpn file to add on top:
>
> ```
>    # A pre script for Private Internet Access
> ```
>
> /etc/openvpn/before_start.sh
>
> That /etc/openvpn/before_start.sh contains:
>
> ```
>    #!/bin/bash
>
>    DNS1=209.222.18.222
>
>    DNS2=209.222.18.218
>
>    ## Change the DNS to avoid DNS Leak
>
>    echo "nameserver $DNS1" > /etc/resolv.conf
>
>    echo "nameserver $DNS2" >> /etc/resolv.conf
> ```
>
> Then into /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf, I added at the end (don't forget to remove 
>   nobind, because I force the local port)
>
> ```
>    lport 1194
>
>    ipchange up_script.sh
>
>    down down_script.sh
> ```
>
> Look up_script.sh (I have improved it with logs and drop of all broadcast address, but I don't have the file right now). The firewall rules are there because I don't know the public IP before. The Gateway allowance is only for 
>   my personal needs, you can remove it
>
> ```
>    #!/bin/bash
>
>    # Firewall Rules
>
>    IP=$(echo $1 | sed 's/\[AF_INET\]//g')
>
>    GW=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
>
>    IPT=iptables
>
>    # Start
>
>    logger "ovpn: Got public IP $IP"
>
>    # tun interfaces (VPN)
>
>    $IPT -A INPUT  -i tun+ -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept TUN Input"
>
>    $IPT -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept TUN Output"
>
>    # Allow traffic with my VPN server
>
>    $IPT -A INPUT  -s $IP -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept PIA Input"
>
>    $IPT -A OUTPUT -d $IP -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept PIA Output"
>
>    # Allow my gateway on eth0
>
>    $IPT -A OUTPUT -d $GW -o eth+ -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept My Gateway"
> ```
>
> Then down_script.sh
>
> ```
>    #!/bin/bash
>
>    GW=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
>
>    IPT=iptables
>
>    # Push DNS again
>
>    echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
>
>    # Restart my interface !
>
>    ifdown -a
>
>    ifup -a
> ```
>
> So what do you think about that ?
>
> G.

Comment: doing this drops output for all users. if i try to drop output only for the one user, it drops all ouput.